# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" with $http.jsonp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, http

Have an application in angularjs. Server have in nodejs and expressjs. Have a problem with jsonp request (error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :).

```
var urlCallback = "http://api.asariweb.pl/apiListing/list?userId=[userId]&loginToken=[loginToken]&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(urlCallback)
   .success(function(data){
       vm.realTimeData = data;
       console.log('vm.realTimeData', vm.realTimeData);
    });
```

In chrome, in "network", i have a good response, only without jsonp wrapper function -

```
{success: true, totalCount: 1368, data: [{id: 5510013, listingId: "3685/2517/OMS", label: null,…},…]}
data: [{id: 5510013, listingId: "3685/2517/OMS", label: null,…},…]
success: true
totalCount: 1368
```

Other url, for example 'https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,audience,onair&ids=xzttq2_c,xrw2w0&callback=JSON_CALLBACK' is working fine.

Comment: is your http call actually returning data wrapped in a callback function?

Comment: http is returning error with undefined data

Comment: is there any reason why you couldn't do an `$http.get`?

Comment: this is another domain

Comment: ok, and when you hit the endpoint in the browser what does it show?

Comment: in browser i have good json.

Comment: problem in jsonp, mayby is any wrapper? for example angular.fromJson(angular.fromJson(data))? but i don't know how use it

Comment: maybe server don't response in jsonp?

Answer (score 0):

in order for `$http.jsonp` to work you need the data returned by your request to be wrapped in a proper callback function:

```
// response 
JSON_CALLBACK({"prop":"value", "prop2":"value2"});
```

Comment: yes, and for this i added &callback=JSON_CALLBACK, but this don't work, and don't know why?

Comment: the callback function has to be included in the api response, so you include the callback and so does the server.

Comment: may be api don't have callback, because other apis working fine

Comment: how can i add this callback into my server in node? Can i do it?